# How should we start a service that doesn't belong to our application and also it is exported, from an implicit intent from our application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I know we should use `setPackage()` method of intent and set it to the package that actually starts the service. But I am confused with what should be the package name. So I have tried using package name given in AndroidManifest.xml, package that contains the service. But none of them works. Everything says such component doesn't exist.

If I don't use `setPackage()` method its working fine in Kitkat but it throws a warning saying using implicit intent is not safe. However, this method doesn't work in Marshmallow.

Comment: if you have running some service named "MyService" and if you call `adb shell dumpsys activity service MyService` you will see something like this: `SERVICE org.my.test.package/.MyService 52b22990 pid=1196` so what you should pass to `setPackage` is `"org.my.test.package"`

Comment: Thanks this helps. And it is working.

Comment: Also packages are generated based on build flavors. So there was a confusion

Comment: good, thats fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package.to.service", "package.to.service.ServiceName"));
ComponentName component = context.startService(i);
```

Remember that package name is this case - package to application, which has a service.

For example, my app with package `com.valentun.myapp` has a service called `ServiceA`.
So, you must set first argument to `"com.valentun.myapp"` and second to `"com.valentun.myapp.ServiceA"`

Comment: I don't need any component name. With package name it works. As @pskink commented it is working